# How to build a c++ program with only an .h file

Tags: c++, makefile

In [the repo for GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest), there is a sample folder with demo tests and files. In the make folder, there is a script to build a program with  `sample1.h` and a `sample1.cc` files (along with the `sample1_unittest.cc`)

```
# Builds a sample test.  A test should link with either gtest.a or
# gtest_main.a, depending on whether it defines its own main()
# function.

sample1.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc $(USER_DIR)/sample1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc

sample1_unittest.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc \
                     $(USER_DIR)/sample1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc

sample1_unittest : sample1.o sample1_unittest.o gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

However, the third sample in the sample folder only has an `.h` file--`sample3-inl.h` which has all the tested code inlined i.e. there is no .cc file. Based on the example above, I tried to build it like you see below but when I run make it says sample3.o doesn't exist

Question: when all the code is inlined in an `.h` file, how to build the program if there's no `.o` file created?

```
 sample3.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample3-inl.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample3-inl.h

sample3_unittest.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample3_unittest.cc \
                     $(USER_DIR)/sample3-inl.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample3_unittest.cc

sample3_unittest : sample3.o sample3_unittest.o gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

Comment: But there ***is*** a `sample3_unittest.cc`...

Comment: @immibis yes, there is a sample3_unittest.cc but there is no sample3.cc (i.e there's only a sample3-inl.h file)

Comment: Perhaps the point is that they're demonstrating how to unit-test a header-only library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample3.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample3-inl.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample3-inl.h -o sample3.o
```

Should do it.  Without the above change, the code was generating `sample3-inl.o` in the `sample3.o` rule.

Or change the input `.o` file later to `sample3-inl.o`.

Comment: ok, it works. Is it expected that it also generates a "sample3-inl.h.gch" file?

Comment: @Leahcim a precompiled header file?  seems reasonable.